# Bokeh server - force refresh client figure before callback returns?

Tags: python, bokeh

With a Bokeh server, is there a way to force the client figure to refresh based on the updated sources part way through a callback function? That is, the callback function has not completed yet, but I want to show some update anyway.

Specifically, I have an application where the user clicks a few positions in a figure, then hits a button to preform a data fitting algorithm. When the button is clicked, a quick initial fitting happens first, then a long fitting process occurs (in separate figures). By default, it seems the initial fit figure does not update as soon as the source updates, but only updates after the callback is completed.

```
initial_fit_data_source = ColumnDataSource(...)
final_fit_data_source = ColumnDataSource(...)

def fitting_callback():
    ... # Perform quick initial fit.
    initial_fit_data_source.data['Fit'] = initial_fit

    # Here I want to update the client's initial fit figure.

    ... # Perform long fitting.
    final_fit_data_source.data['Fit'] = final_fit
```

Is there a way to preform this refresh during the callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Bokeh can send out document updates only when the execution makes its way back into the event loop. To do that, you can either use async functions everywhere or wrap separate steps in parameterless functions and pass them to `document.add_next_tick_callback`. Either way, it's better to also wrap all blocking computations in threads: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#updating-from-threads